# Check if the button is pressed or not

Tags: python, pygame

Is there any function to check if the mouse button is pressed or not . MOUSEBUTTONDOWN doesn't work

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_pos = event.pos
```

I have to release the button then press it again , then the code works .
If I kept pressing the button it doesn't work

I want that if I kept pressing the button , the code still works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pygame.mouse.get_pressed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) to get list of button states.

Another way of achieving that is by polling every event and setting your value to `True` on `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events and to `False` on `MOUSEBUTTONUP` events.

Comment: "*Just don't forget about setting it to False in MOUSEBUTTONUP event.*"? What does that mean? You don't need to do that

Comment: Well, if they don't set it back to False in MOUSEBUTTONUP event, it will be stuck at True after first mouse press

Comment: So you are saying that you are putting `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` in the `if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`? That makes no sense, just put `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` in the main loop. You don't need to put this instruction in the `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop.

Comment: I mean, that you can use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed` OR check for every event and if it's `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, set your value to True and if it is `MOUSEBUTTONUP`, set it to False. That's two solutions to one problem. Maybe I should describe it better

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But the easiest solution, the simplest, the shortest, and the one which uses the least amount of time is the use of `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` here.